# Create template function for function that accepts function pointers as parameters for many types of functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, function-pointers, function-declaration

I have several c functions that do pretty much the exact same thing except for functions on one line. I want to replace all of these functions with one function that I can pass as function pointer for that one line:

```
Func1(type parameter);

Func2(type1 parameter1,type2 parameter2);

FuncFunc(FunctionPointer functionPointer){
    funcVar;
    ...
    functionPointer(funcVar,....);
    ...
}

int main(){
    FuncFunc(Func1);

    FuncFunc(Func2(,type2Object));
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this in C++?

Comment: This can certainly be done in C++. However, your question is somewhat unclear. "several c functions that do pretty much the exact same thing except for functions on one line" -- this is completely unparsable. Can you extrapolate and give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but here is an example how your code may me translated into valid C++. First, let's define your `Func` with maximum number of arguments:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Func(T1 par1, T2 par2) {
        std::cout << par1 << " " << par2 << std::endl;
}
```

Then we should make `FuncFunc` accept any function you want:

```
template<typename ...T>
void FuncFunc(const std::function<void(T...)>& fPtr) {
        std::string funcVar = "Foo!";
        fPtr(funcVar);
}
```

or easier to use variant:

```
template<typename F>
void GuncFunc(const F& fPtr) {
        std::string funcVar = "Foo!";
        fPtr(funcVar);
}
```

and finally use `FuncFunc`:

```
auto Func1 = std::bind(Func<float, std::string>, 3.14f, std::placeholders::_1);
auto Func2 = std::bind(Func<std::string, int>, std::placeholders::_1, 42);
FuncFunc(std::function<void(std::string)>(Func1));
FuncFunc(std::function<void(std::string)>(Func2));
return 0;
```

or `GuncFunc`:

```
// Using std::bind
GuncFunc(std::bind(Func<float, std::string>, 3.14f, std::placeholders::_1));
GuncFunc(std::bind(Func<std::string, int>, std::placeholders::_1, 42));

// Or using lambdas:
GuncFunc([](std::string s){Func<float, std::string>(3.14f, s);});
GuncFunc([](std::string s){Func<std::string, int>(s, 42);});
```

Choosing `std::bind` or lambdas seems to be out of scope of your question, but you may found something useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852764/stdbind-vs-lambda-performance) or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14) question.

Anyway, very likely you will need [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: You could also use (and probably should prefer) lambdas instead of `std::bind`