# Using lambdas with Boost Beast instead of bind

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, boost-beast

In [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp), if I change this call with bind:

```
boost::asio::async_connect(
        socket_,
        results.begin(),
        results.end(),
        std::bind(
            &session::on_connect,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));
```

To this:

```
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    boost::asio::async_connect(
                socket_,
                results.begin(),
                results.end(),
                [self](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        self->on_connect(ec);
    });
```

I get an assertion error:

```
boost/boost/asio/impl/connect.hpp:761: error: static_assert failed "IteratorConnectHandler type requirements not met"
  BOOST_ASIO_ITERATOR_CONNECT_HANDLER_CHECK(
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There's a comment there:

```
// If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
// not meet the documented type requirements for a IteratorConnectHandler.
```

I personally [don't prefer bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45712553/1317944), and would like to change it to lambda. Am I doing it wrong or is this a little bug in boost::beast?

By the way changing to a lambda for `on_resolve` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of parameters of your lambda doesn't match to handler signature, according to reference [async_connect](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect/overload1.html) handlers takes `error_code` and *connected endpoint* - it is missing in your case.

Fix:

```
auto self = shared_from_this();
boost::asio::async_connect(
            socket_,
            results.begin(),
            results.end(),
            [self](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator) {
                                                 ^^^
    self->on_connect(ec);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could replace `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` with `auto` if you don't care to spell it out or use it

Comment: Yep, you are right, `auto` could be used in this case if OP uses at least C++14.
But to provide more self-documented code the full name may be better choice.