# Use std::bind and store into a std:: function

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I am trying to use std::bind to bind to a function and store it into my std::function callback object. The code I wrote is the simplified version of my actual code. The below code does not compile, says

> *_1 was not declared in the scope*

Note: I know the same can be done using a lambda. However the function handler is already present and need to be used else I need to call the handler inside the lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std:: function<void(int)> Callback;

template <class T>
class Add
{
public:
    Add(Callback c)
    {
        callback = c;
    }
    void add(T a, T b)
    {
        callback(a+b);
    }

private:
    Callback callback;
};

void handler(int res)
{
    printf("result = %d\n", res);
}

int main(void) 
{
    // create a callback
    // I know it can be done using lambda
    // but I want to use bind to handler here 
    Callback c = std::bind(handler, _1);
    
    /*Callback c = [](int res)
    {
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
    };*/
    
    // create template object with 
    // the callback object
    Add<int> a(c);
    a.add(10,20);
}
```

Comment: `_1` is in the `std::placeholders` namespace not the global namespace

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why you want to  use one technique that's inferior  to an other ,lamdas are not about personal style it is just something that is suggested and in a lot of cases it is faster that bind [lamda vs bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852764/stdbind-vs-lambda-performance)

Comment: I know. Actually this function is a legacy function so I thought of just binding it to the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholders `_1`, `_2`, `_3`... are placed in namespace `std::placeholders`, you should qualify it like

```
Callback c = std::bind(handler, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Or

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
Callback c = std::bind(handler, _1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders are in own namespace in the std namespace.
Add `using namespace std::placeholders` or use `std::placeholders::_1`

Good examples: [std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, ..., std::placeholders::_N](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)